# Using git branches for multiple developers

Tags: git, github

We have a project, that has multiple developers. Each developer has his own feature branch and once the feature is complete, it is merged with master and pushed to the remote repository. The problem arises:

1. If several people are working on features and they all push their changes and one of the features is buggy. Is there a way all of the features can be pushed to a secondary master in remote, run tests and if everything goes well, push to the master in the remote?
2. Lets say all the developers are working on their feature and an emergency fix comes up, how is that best handled? It is possible that some of the developers have pushed already, but we want to push only the emergency fix?

Comment: Instead of every developer having his own branch, consider having them do all the prep work in their own repo, however they want to do it, then clean up the history for publication and do their own merge to a public testing branch, and master gets fast-forwarded to that once it passes.  Developers know their own code best and can generally do the rebases trivially, and there's no reason at all to have messy history in production.  Even if you don't want purely linear, I'd say it's best to have wip commits done privately, rely on collaboration to keep any overlapping private work in sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad 1. Yes, it is possible. Just create another branch in the remote repo as the "secondary master" if you wish so. You can name it whatever you like, for example *devel*.

Ad 2. Our team has branch called *production*, which should be the exact same version of what is running on production servers and from which we are deploying. So when we need to apply hotfix, we don't have to worry about the current status of *master* - we just apply it to *production*.

I recommend to read this, at least for inspiration: [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: Great link! +1 for that, very useful to have some "best practices"!

Comment: Thank you for the link. So one question in the model you are suggesting, having a secondary master means a lot of people are pushing features, some can be buggy, if people don't revert those commits they can be left behind...a lot of messy situation can arise because it requires constant co-ordination and communication. How do I get around that?

Comment: @Mark I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. Usually _master_ is kept as a most recent, but stable version of codebase. Any development that could bring _master_ to non-stable state is done in its own feature branch instead. After it is done or when it reaches some stability it could be merged into master. Also master is merged to this feature branch from time to time to keep it up to date with other changes.

Comment: If you want to have _secondary master_ as a mix of all unstable feature branches with unfinished/untested/broken code then of course it will be mess.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all easy to do with git. The idea would be this:

- One `master` branch which is "stable"
- One `staging` branch which tracks master and gets the feature merges first: this is where final testing is done.
- Numerous feature branches.

If an emergency fix is done on master, this can be handled in several ways:

- cherry-pick the commit to each feature branch. You can also apply the fix to some other branch and cherry-pick from there. Cherry-picking is extremely localized, and can go across to and from any branch (in principle).
- merge master into the feature branch, including any "upstream" changes in one go
- rebase the feature branch onto master. This is essentially the previous item, with one major difference: a rebase will rewind and replay all the branch's commits onto the tip of master, so when the branch is merged after rebasing, it will have a very linear implementation history, and all the branch's commits come in a consecutive series.